# Centering a container with jQuery before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` and an `img` that need centering on the window.I have extended jQuery functionality in order to do that using this function:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
                this.css("position","absolute");
                this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) +$(window).scrollTop()) + "px");

                this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) +  $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");

                return this;
            }
```

This function works perfectly but the only problem is that the image first loads on it's default position and then is moved to the center.How can I make the image been seen directly on center on page load?

**EDIT**:Here is what I meant: [www.foxteam.net/portfolio.php](http://www.foxteam.net/portfolio.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually need to see the code that calls this function to help you out, but here's a quick suggestion.

Render the img first with `display:none;` and chain your `.fadeIn()` function right after `.center()`
or make it synchronous using a callback.

This way, you are centering the image even before showing it.